# Load XML has multiple namespaces to SQL usnig SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis, namespaces

i'm trying to load the below XML to SQL using SSIS, but my XML have multiple namespace and I used XML Task component to convert in to XSLT and it's not working :

Note: unable to replace ns5: manually

I need to load the below XML to SQL server

```
<THExport>
<Txn>
    <ns5:ID>1160013</ns5:ID>
    <ns5:LinkID>1130037</ns5:LinkID>
    <ns5:BucketType>1</ns5:BucketType>
    <ns5:Date>20151125105715</ns5:Date>
    <ns5:ExtRef>15</ns5:ExtRef>
    <ns5:Type>18</ns5:Type>
    <ns5:Mode>2</ns5:Mode>
    <ns5:VoidStatus>0</ns5:VoidStatus>
    <ns5:FailedStatus>0</ns5:FailedStatus>
    <ns5:Source>11</ns5:Source>
    <ns5:PurchAmt>888.88</ns5:PurchAmt>
    <ns5:DiscAmt>0.0</ns5:DiscAmt>
    <ns5:RdmAmt>10.0</ns5:RdmAmt>
    <ns5:AdjAmt>878.88</ns5:AdjAmt>
    <ns5:AccountID>/XID/2000000000/200000000050</ns5:AccountID>
    <ns5:ProductID>/EID/3000000002/411420******0050</ns5:ProductID>
    <ns5:MerchantID>000000000011111</ns5:MerchantID>
    <ns5:MerchantName>Kinokuniya Orchard</ns5:MerchantName>
    <ns5:DeviceID>00001111</ns5:DeviceID>
    <ns5:Operation>
        <ns5:Type>2</ns5:Type>
        <ns5:Entity>
            <ns3:Type>PL</ns3:Type>
            <ns3:ID>262</ns3:ID>
            <ns3:Number>262</ns3:Number>
            <ns3:Name>MonPL_ARJ</ns3:Name>
        </ns5:Entity> 
       <ns5:AuxEntity>
            <ns5:Type>OF</ns5:Type>
            <ns5:ID>125</ns5:ID>
            <ns5:Name>MonPOSItemOffer_ARJ</ns5:Name>
            <ns5:Channel>POS</ns5:Channel>
            <ns5:Nature>I</ns5:Nature>
            <ns5:Quantity>1.0</ns5:Quantity>
        </ns5:AuxEntity>
        <ns5:Amount>-5.0</ns5:Amount>
        <ns5:ExpiryDate>20161124</ns5:ExpiryDate>
    </ns5:Operation>
    <ns5:Operation>
        <ns5:Type>2</ns5:Type>
        <ns5:Entity>
            <ns3:Type>PL</ns3:Type>
            <ns3:ID>262</ns3:ID>
            <ns3:Number>262</ns3:Number>
            <ns3:Name>MonPL_ARJ</ns3:Name>
        </ns5:Entity>                    * Offer details for point redemption from the first pool expiry slot              <ns5:AuxEntity>
            <ns5:Type>OF</ns5:Type>
            <ns5:ID>125</ns5:ID>
            <ns5:Name>MonPOSItemOffer_ARJ</ns5:Name>
            <ns5:Channel>POS</ns5:Channel>
            <ns5:Nature>I</ns5:Nature>
            <ns5:Quantity>0.0</ns5:Quantity>
        </ns5:AuxEntity>
        <ns5:Amount>-5.0</ns5:Amount>
        <ns5:ExpiryDate>20161125</ns5:ExpiryDate>
    </ns5:Operation>
</Txn>
```

Comment: You need to edit your post and add both (1) original XML and (2) XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XML Task component with the below code to fix the multi namespace the XML file then read the XML using XML source in SSIS :